# The problematic UX/UI of all Stack Exchange sites - Why don't they make any of these things better already?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

Hey I'm going to finally start learning programming and making stuff and I was wondering this:

As an example, if you look at -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github?sort=votes&pageSize=15

- You can't filter by within the last year, custom dates, etc. (Google, YouTube, Quora, Amazon, etc. can all do this)
- You also cannot filter by questions that have answers
- More importantly, maybe even most, you can't filter by questions that have 'greened' answers.

This actually makes Stack Exchange very unusable for me when I'm trying to learn on any particular topic/tag

Besides extreme fragmentation of info, not being able to do much filtering is a huge burden.

I don't read Stack Exchange or really come across Stack Exchange sites when googling. **I Quora.** In fact, I Quora so much that I have a "429. Too Many Requests. Please email errors@quora.com if you believe this is an error. Please include your IP address in your email." -- **yet again!**

Even when I come across Stack Exchange sites, I consciously do not click on it, as so many questions have no answers, or have answers, but no solutions.

Stack Exchange/overflow has **certain kinds of information** that would be helpful for learning though. currently (for the last 10 years I guess), it's just VERY VERY difficult to find, search, etc.

I'm guessing people have said similar things in the past. **It's just completely un-usable for me right now.**

I understand that there may be backend/legacy stuff that makes this a challenge, but seriously, don't they have smart people? And I don't care -- **that's not a solution** (none of us needs talk, **we need solutions**)

Comment: You can do all of these things at the moment... You're just not looking at the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: ok.... well, because of how extremely difficult it was to find http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching (have to ask), i coud've been using SE the whole time... haha....

Comment: just for the record, this overall problem stated in the question still exist -- you can easily find basic filters on other sites, but you can't on here

Comment: Click on help at the top of every page, then click on Help Centre, then searching. If you follow "help" it's in the logical place ... It's also available once you've searched for something. If you've got a better suggestion the ask another question ([tag:feature-request]) with _only_ that and a suggestion where else would be a good place.

Comment: think the page should be more easily accessible on stackoverflow.com/questions/ or any tag pages. a site shouldn't be for just geniuses as you say on your linkedin -- "creating something new why not make it easy to understand, reusable and performant at the beginning?"

Comment: dont think anyone would care but threw that concern of better UX/UI out there -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265983/one-suggestion-about-searching-for-better-ux-ui-curing-one-pain-point

Comment: For what it's worth, I did not discover any of these filters through the help center, but through the "Advanced Search Tips" link that appears in the top right whenever you do a regular search. The help center lists even more filters, but that link was fairly easy to discover (could be easi*er*, but still fairly easy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're viewing a tag, you're essentially running a search and you can use all of the bonus [search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) available to you. The system even automatically fills in the search box with the tag(s) you're currently looking at, so you don't have to type it again. Just click in the box at the top right and add whatever you'd like.

> You can't filter by within the last year, etc.

You can use the time search operator. For example, to find questions created within the last year, you can use `created:1y...` in your search.

> You also cannot filter by questions that have answers.

You can use the minimum answers search operator. Just add `answers:1` to search for only questions which have at least one answer on them (or however many you want to require) *or* use `isanswered:1` to return questions which have at least one *upvoted* answer on them.

> You can't filter by questions that have 'greened' answers.

I'm assuming you mean accepted when you say greened. If so, use the has accepted search operator: it's simply `hasaccepted:1` in your search.

---

Due to the variety of search operations available, implementing all of this stuff into a UI would be painful and hideous. There's just too much to fit on a page. Some of the more basic ones are implemented into some of the tabs to easily access, but the rest you will just have to know they exist and how to use them.

Comment: thanks, can't accept for 5 mins... going to make a default custom search for SO/SE on chrome after reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching ....

Answer (score 0):

Search for `[github] is:question hasaccepted:yes`.

The `is:question` flag lets you search for things that are questions. `hasaccepted:yes` forces the question to have an accepted answer. If you want the most recent stuff, sort by "newest" in the tab selection.

Comment: If you want to help the OP out you're missing `isanswered:yes` as the last one that was being queried.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards `isanswered:yes` is overridden by `hasaccepted:yes`, because there must be an answer for there to be an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it could be part of a different query if you're demonstrating the functionality the OP is looking for though.

Comment: thanks, can't accept for 5 mins... going to make a default custom search for SO/SE on chrome after reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching ....